# Event listener not getting detached

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, event-handling, flex3

I am registering an event listener using Mate:Listener as

```
<mate:Listener method="getSettingListner" type="{SettingEvent.GET_VIDEO_SETTING}" useWeakReference="true"/>
```

and trying to detach it when am done with my work like

```
this.removeEventListener(SettingEvent.GET_VIDEO_SETTING,getSettingListner);
```

But, while debugging i can still see that the method is still listening to the event. Why?

How can i detach an event listener which was attached using mate?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, per [this post](http://mate.asfusion.com/page/documentation/tags/listener) on the Mate Forums.  It advises you to either set the 'type' property to null, or use ListenerInjector as Listener is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I could achieve this by doing event.target.removeEventListener(SettingEvent.GET_VIDEO_SETTING,getSettingListner);